# how does this work in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

hello I am having difficulty writing this code, I am lost on the last two methods. This is  a learning exercise (not homework),  but I need examples to learn.
Plus I thought this would be useful in the stackoverflow database as well.

```
public class NumberList {

public int[] values;  

public NumberList() {
    values = new int[0];
}

public NumberList(int[] a) {
values = new int [a.length];
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
values[i] = a[i];
}

public int getSize() {
    return this.values.length;

}

public int getAt(int index) {
    if (index>=values.length){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ("Values of out of bounds");
    }else{
        return values[index];
    }
}

public long getTotal() {
    long sum = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + values[i];
      }
      return sum;



}
// need help here its a boolean that the number is in the array but if not its //false
public boolean contains(int number) {

     for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++){ 
        if (number <values.length+1){ 
            return true;

     }
     //else 
        // return false;
    // }


// this is an add method that confuses me and ask myself why since i added without it.
public void add(int number) {
     number=0;



}

}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked any questions.  Is the problem the add method?  What should it do, add a new index to the array?

Comment: Could you give a set of inputs and what their expected outputs are?

Comment: You don't need to check the array bounds, Java does this for you and throws the same exception, except maybe if you want your message instead of default one.

Comment: Take a look at System.arrayCopy()

Comment: Actually, this seems to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573534/java-noobie-array-program-what-is-wrong-with-my-code/5573622#5573622

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public boolean contains(int number) {
     for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) 
          if (number==values[i]) return true;
     return false;
}

public void add(int number) {
     int[] tmp = new int[value.length+1];
     for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) tmp[i] = values[i];
     tmp[tmp.length-1] = number;
     values = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great start. All you needed to change was the following:

```
public boolean contains(int number) {

    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) { 
        if (values[i] == number) { 
            return true;
    }

    // Since this line is reached only if no values matched, you simply do...
    return false;
}
```

---

Since you're still learning, I'll give you a few more pointers as a bonus :-)

- I would change

  ```
  if (index >= values.length)
  ```

  to

  ```
  if (index < 0 || index >= values.length)
  ```
- You could make use of for-each loops here and there. You could for instance write:

  ```
  public long getTotal() {
      long sum = 0;
      for (int i : values)
          sum = sum + i;

      return sum;
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you have any tips? or great books to learn from? I go to a top computer science school thats insanely hard and im trying my best to survive. I study like 18 hours a day any help in learning and im very grateful!

Comment: Doesn't that assume the array only contains increasing numbers, and every number from 1 to length? For example if array is {1, 3, 5} and you pass in contains(2) that would return true, but it's actually false

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: What if the method was meant to check if the array contained a value for that index?  It's hard to tell what is wrong without knowing more about the code.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like below:

```
public boolean contains(int number) {

     for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++){ 
        //so the number was found
        if (number==values[i]){ 
            return true;

     }
     return false; 
  }
```

You can also use [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) method instead of writing one yourself. The binary search will find if the number is in the array and what index (of course the array has to be ordered).

Answer (score 1):

Some of these methods can be simplified.

```
public NumberList(int[] a) {
    values = a.clone();
}

public int getAt(int index) {
    return values[index]; // throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if out of bounds. It include the invalid index as well.
}

public long getTotal() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i: values) sum += i;
    return sum;
}

public boolean contains(int number) {
    for (int i: values) 
        if (number == i)
            return true;
    return false;
}

public void add(int num) {
    int[] values2 = new int[values.length+1];
    // arraycopy is typically faster than using a loop.
    System.arraycopy(values,0,value2,0,values.length);
    values2[values.length] = num;
    values = values2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method:

```
public boolean contains(int number) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    {
        if (number == values[i])
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Second Method: For this you have to maintain a variable called `current` that contains the index of the most recently added element.

```
public void add(int number)
{
    if(current == values.length - 1)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Array Overflow");
    }

    values[++current] = number;
}
```